# How can I fix Argument labels '(bytes:, length:)' do not match any available overloads error?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have converted an Objective-C project to Swift 4 and I am getting the following error on the line below:

> Argument labels '(bytes:, length:)' do not match any available overloads

**Swift**

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x80, 0xbe, 0xf5, 0xac, 0xff], length: 5)
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(Byte[]){0x80,0xBE,0xF5,0xAC,0xFF} length:5];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the `length` part, there's no need for it in `Swift`.

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x80, 0xbe, 0xf5, 0xac, 0xff])
```

Or you can even omit the `bytes` argument label:

```
let data = Data([0x80, 0xbe, 0xf5, 0xac, 0xff])
```

Comment: You can even omit `bytes:`

Comment: To complement vadian's comment Data conforms to RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection, RangeReplaceableCollection

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for the answer.

Comment: To add slightly more explanation: `Data` has an `init(bytes:)` which takes a `[UInt8]` or `ArraySlice<UInt8>` argument. It also has an `init(_:)` which takes any `Sequence` of `UInt8` as an argument; which `[UInt8]` is. I don't know why they bothered to keep `init(bytes:)` around though, as it's just a less generic version of `init(_:)`.